# Output Befor giving the input of string for finding palindrome

Tags: c++, getline, palindrome, stdstring

This code is giving output YES just after entering the value of test case.
Code: for alphanumeric pallindrome

```
int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        string s;
        int count = 0,size = 0;
        getline(cin,s);
        cout<<s<<endl;
        s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(),s.end(),not1(ptr_fun((int(*)(int))isalnum))), s.end());
        for(int i=0;i<=s.size()/2;i++){
            size++;
            if(tolower(s[i])==tolower(s[s.size()-i-1])){
                count++;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        if (count==size)
            cout<<"YES"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"NO"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output I am getting is YES without giving any input of string

```
For Input:
2
I am :IronnorI Ma, i
Ab?/Ba
Your Output is:

YES
I am :IronnorI Ma, i
YES
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some headers and misspelling some types (assuming that `string` is supposed to be `std::string` and `tolower` should be `std::tolower`, etc.)

Comment: I used using namespace std so there is no use of std::

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Comment: It did nor gave me any problem till now and I already got the solution of my problem mentioned below. Seems like std was not an issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code is giving output YES just after entering the value of test
>   case. Output I am getting is YES without giving any input of string

Your problem is here:

```
/* code */
    cin>>t;    -----------> std::cin        
    while(t--)
    {
        string s;
        int count = 0,size = 0;
        getline(cin,s); ------------> std::getline()

/* remaining code */
```

Reading with something like `std::cin` leaves the newline in the input stream. When the flow of control reaches `std::getline()`, the newline will be discarded, but the input will cease immediately. This leads, `std::getline()`s attempt read a new line and skips the input.

**FIX**: When switching from white space delimited to newline delimited input, you want to clean all newlines from the input stream by doing a `std::cin.ignore()`

The fixed code should be: https://www.ideone.com/ucDa7i#stdin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    // fix
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    while(t--)
    {
        std::string s;
        int count = 0,size = 0;
        getline(std::cin,s);
        /* remaining code */
}
```